# Why my variable type char using variable++ or variable+1 return different returns?

Tags: c

I'm learning C, malloc and pointers specifially, I'm testing this code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(){

char test[5] = "ayolw";
printf(" \nmy string : %s\n", test);

char *testa = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char));
testa = test;

printf("%c", *testa);
printf("%c", *testa+1);
printf("%c", *testa+2);
printf("%c", *testa+3);
printf("%c\n", *testa+4);

while(*testa!='\0'){
    printf("%c ", *testa);
    *testa++;
}
printf("\n\n");

return 0;
}
```

My output:

```
my string : ayolw
abcde // output using *testa+1,*test+2,...;
a y o l w // output using *testa++;
```

I understand my first output are returning testa[0] ASCII value + number. howhever why using *testa++ are returning correctly if testa++ is equivalent to testa+1

And another question, how can I print my output using a lign like `*testa+2` if I can't use testa[2]. That its possible?

Comment: One factor at play here is [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence); `*testa+1` is evaluated as `(*testa)+1`, whereas `*testa++` is evaluated as `*(testa++)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> howhever why using *testa++ are returning correctly if testa++ is equivalent to testa+1

Because `testa++` is *not* equivalent to `testa+1`.  Not even very close.  It differs in several significant regards, among them:

1. `testa++` evaluates to the value of `testa`, and as a side effect, *modifies `testa`'s stored value*, increasing that by 1.  On the other hand, `testa+1` evaluates to one more than the value of `testa` and does not modify `testa`'s stored value.
2. The postfix `++` operator has higher precedence than unary `*`, whereas the binary `+` operator has lower precedence than unary `*`.  That means that `*testa+1` is equivalent to `(*testa)+1`, whereas `*testa++` is equivalent to `*(testa++)`.

Taking these together,

- the value of `testa` does not change in the various `*testa+x` cases.  It always points at the first character of `test`, and the `*testa` part always evaluates to the value of that character.  The addition is applied to that character value (promoted to an `int`).
- the value of `testa` *does* change in the various `*testa++` cases.  Each evaluation of that expression returns the character to which `testa` currently points, and also updates `testa` to point to the next character.

---

As a separate matter, note that in ...

> ```
> char *testa = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char));
> testa = test;
> ```

...

- you do not need to cast the return value of `malloc()` in C, nor should you.
- that particular `malloc()` is wasteful, as you immediately replace the only pointer to the allocated memory with a pointer to the first byte of array `test`.  The dynamically allocated memory is leaked.  Better would be any of

  ```
  char *testa;
  testa = test;
  ```

  OR

  ```
  char *testa = test;
  ```

  OR

  ```
  char *testa;
  testa = &test[0];
  ```

  OR

  ```
  char *testa = &test[0];
  ```

  , all of which are equivalent to each other for your definition of `test` as an array of `char`.

Comment: I'm trying malloc just for future situations where I need read and assign a string with unknowed size of string. thanks for explanation

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't have `testa++` and `testa+1`, you have `*(testa++)` vs `(*testa)+1`. Notice that you are adding one to different things.

Secondly, `x++` is NOT equivalent to `x+1`. `++x` is closer, but it's not equivalent either.

`x++` evaluates to the original value of `x`. Assigns `x` plus 1 to `x`.

`x+1` evaluates to `x` plus 1. Does not modify `x`.

`++x` evaluates to `x` plus 1. Assigns `x` plus 1 to `x`.